# Can't start kmemleak, echo appeared "Operation not permitted"

Tags: memory-leaks, linux-kernel, yocto

I have a yocto image installed to my HW, but I got some kernel memory leak problem and would like to install kmemleak to check. But `cat /sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak` shows nothing since somehow my kmemleak being disable.

I enable kmemleak in my linux kernel build. But  `echo scan > /sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak` showing `-sh: echo: write error: Operation not permitted`

Here is the output of something I've tried:

```
$ dmesg | grep kmemleak
kmemleak: Kernel memory leak detector disabled

$ zcat /proc/config.gz | grep CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK
CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_MEM_POOL_SIZE=2048
CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_TEST=m
CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_DEFAULT_OFF=y
CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_AUTO_SCAN=y

$ mount -t debugfs nodev /sys/kernel/debug/
mount: /sys/kernel/debug: nodev already mounted or mount point busy.

$ cat /proc/mounts | grep debugfs
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0

$ ls -l /sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root             0 Jan  4 04:30 /sys/kernel/debug/kmemleak

$ mount | grep debug
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/debug type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,debug)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

Also learned that if kmemleak=off then it would not be enable, but I've checked and it seemed fine:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/bzImage root=/dev/sda2 console=tty0,115200n8 console=ttyS0,115200n8 console=ttyO0,115200n8 console=ttyAMA0,115200n8 rootwait
```

I also try to increase the size of CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_MEM_POOL_SIZE but still no luck.

Comment: Because `CONFIG_DEBUG_KMEMLEAK_DEFAULT_OFF=y`, you need the boot parameter `kmemleak=on` to enable it.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you, it took me awhile to figure out how to add boot parameter because it's kind of strange a little bit, but I got it going, thank you