# Memory leaks in Yocto image

Tags: memory-leaks, linux-kernel, yocto, kernel-module

I detect a memory leak in Yocto (kirkstone version, kernel 5.15) and I've tried bunch of way but still the "used" field in "free -m" keeps getting bigger and bigger

1. I have tried to install kmemleak but no success. I think there probably some restriction in my system since I've tried every way I can find in the internet to enable it but still dmesg show kmemleak disable.
2. I tried to install KERD, using cross-compiled linux modules with Yocto SDK environment but there is error in missmatched Kbuild version, hence I can't install KERD as well.
3. I tried to remove all the loaded modules 1 by 1 to see which one is the cause, but still nothing change.
4. My kernel has 1 added builtin kernel module, but even disable it doesn't solve the problem

I've running out of thoughts and ways how to check this. Is anyone an expert in kernel memory leak can help me a hand?

Comment: See my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77826402/#comment137215656_77826402) on your other question to enable kmemleak.